# Move the files to a specific folder in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a script to move files of type .txt to a particular folder .It looks for the files in *work* folder and move it to completed folder.
I would like to make the script generic i.e to enhance the script so that the scripts works not for just one particular folder but other similar folders as well.
Example: If there is a .txt file in folder /tmp/swan/test/work and also in folder /tmp/swan/test11/work, the files should move to /tmp/swan/test/done and /tmp/swan/test11/done respectively. 
EDIT:Also, if there is a .txt file in a sub folder like /tmp/swan/test11/work/APX that should also move to /tmp/swan/test11/done

Below is the current script.

```
  #!/bin/bash

  MY_DIR=/tmp/swan

  cd $MY_DIR

  find .  -path "*work*"  -iname "*.txt" -type f -execdir mv '{}' /tmp/swan/test/done \;
```

Answer (score 2):

With `-execdir`, the `mv` command is executed in whatever directory the file is found in. Since you just want to move the file to a "sibling" directory, each command can use the same relative path `../done`.

```
find . -path "*work*"  -iname "*.txt" -type f -execdir mv '{}' ../done \;
```

Comment: The script you gave works fine if its a sibling directory, but I have a .txt file in folder /tmp/swan/test11/work/APX and I want this file to be moved to /tmp/swan/test11/done as well . Sorry I missed this detail initially.

Comment: Are you using `bash` 4 or later, by any chance?

Comment: I am using bash version 3.2.25 . With the script you provided ,it creates a .txt file in  /tmp/swan/test11/work when I try to move a *.txt file from /tmp/swan/test11/work/APX instead of moving to the folder /tmp/swan/test11/done

Comment: No, I was just going to suggest a `find`-free solution if you were using `bash` 4.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

**Background:**

```
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── work
└── b
    └── work
```

**Renaming:**

```
find . -type f -name work -exec \
sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(dirname "$1")"/done' -- {} \;
```

**Output:**

```
mv ./a/work ./a/done
mv ./b/work ./b/done
```

You can remove the `echo` if it does what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
find . -path '*work/*.txt' -exec sh -c 'd=$(dirname $(dirname $1))/done; mkdir -p $d; mv $1 $d' _ {} \;
```

(also creates the target directory if it does not exist already).